# Spring Boot Reference Guide - get 404 from app.groovy example

Tags: java, spring-boot

I follow [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-run) and got this error

```
HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]
Type Status Report
Message /
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Here is the code

```
@RestController
class ThisWillActuallyRun {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Command that I run.

```
spring run app.groovy
```

Console log that I got.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)

2017-07-21 14:37:37.474  INFO 47637 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on MacBook-Pro-2016.local with PID 47637 (started by moss in /Users/moss/java_ws/hello)
2017-07-21 14:37:37.477  INFO 47637 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-07-21 14:37:37.659  INFO 47637 --- [       runner-0] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3a0184b7: startup date [Fri Jul 21 14:37:37 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-21 14:37:38.831  INFO 47637 --- [       runner-0] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-07-21 14:37:38.844  INFO 47637 --- [       runner-0] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-07-21 14:37:38.846  INFO 47637 --- [       runner-0] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-07-21 14:37:38.923  INFO 47637 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader  : Unknown loader org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader$DefaultScopeParentClassLoader@c0454ed class org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader$DefaultScopeParentClassLoader
2017-07-21 14:37:38.950  INFO 47637 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-07-21 14:37:38.951  INFO 47637 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1296 ms
2017-07-21 14:37:39.020  INFO 47637 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-21 14:37:39.605  INFO 47637 --- [       runner-0] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-07-21 14:37:39.674  INFO 47637 --- [       runner-0] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-07-21 14:37:39.678  INFO 47637 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 12.556 seconds (JVM running for 14.572)
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What version of the Spring CLI are you using?

Comment: `Spring CLI v1.5.4.RELEASE`

Comment: @chrylis I have try to create another file in different directory but result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use `sdkman` switch back to `Spring CLI v1.5.3.RELEASE` and it's work.